# Re-enable jQuery validation after disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have an MVC project where I am using the built in validation using data annotations with jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.  This all works fine and my form will validate.

On one form I have a postcode lookup button so I have disabled the validation for this button by using the suggestions by adding the `formnovalidate` attribute to the button.  This also works well and allows me to submit the form to do my postcode lookup using ajax.

After I have clicked this button, I can then click on the main submit button and it will post the form without any validation happening.

I have had a look in the jquery.validate.js file and have seen that the validation is cancelled using this code:

```
// allow suppressing validation by adding the html5 formnovalidate attribute to the submit button
if ( $(event.target).attr("formnovalidate") !== undefined ) {
    validator.cancelSubmit = true;
}
```

I can then re-enable it by adding this after:

```
if ( event.target.id == 'submit' ) {
    validator.cancelSubmit = false;
}
```

However I don't want to change the source file as if I do an update using nuget I may forget that I have altered that file and forget to put that line back in.

How would I bind the `validator.cancelSubmit = false;` to the button click - something like this (which won't work as I don't have the `validator` object):

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    validator.cancelSubmit = false;
});
```

I have tried using `$.validator.cancelSubmit = false;` but this didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `validator` object using `data()`:

```
$(yourForm).data('validator').cancelSubmit = false;
```

Comment: Sorry was called into a meeting.  This is works perfectly, thanks!